# Find the lightest and second lightest balls among n balls

Tags: algorithms

I have `n` balls t<sub>1</sub>, ..., t<sub>n</sub>. `n` is a power of 3. All the balls have different weights. The only measurement tool I have available is a three-way scale: I put three balls on the scale and it shows me which is the lightest, which is the heaviest, and which is in the middle. This a three-way-comparison.

I want to simultaneously find the lightest and the second lightest balls.

I am trying to prove that using at most  $\lceil$$\frac{n}{2}$$\rceil$ + $\lceil$$\frac{\log _{3}n}{2}$$\rceil$ three way comparisons, I can simultaneously find both the lightest and the second lightest balls.

I know that for 3 balls, I can put them all on the scale and find the lightest and the second lightest. But I'm confused on how to go from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, find the lightest ball as fast as possible, i.e., divide the balls into group of $3$, make comparisons, and keep the lightest balls only, then divide them into group of $3$ again, and so on, which takes
$$\frac{n}{3}+\frac{n}{9}+\dots\leq \sum_{i=1}^\infty \frac{n}{3^i}\leq \lceil\frac{n}{2}\rceil$$
comparisons. After that, we can also find that the second lightest ball must be one of the balls that are shown middle during one comparison containing the lightest ball. As the lightest ball takes part in $\log_3 n$ comparisons, there are only $\log_3 n$ possible choices. By exactly the same method as above, we can find the second lightest ball in $\lceil \log_3 n/2\rceil$comparisons.